# Javascript generate images more complex than canvases

Tags: javascript, node.js

so im trying to generate an image in javascript that will look something like this 5 colored Rectangles next to each other:
[image]

based on color codes I also generate

I tried to use javascript canvases but from reading the documentation it doesnt seem something like this is possible with it.

thank you for all the help

Comment: This looks exactly like what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004658/4584472

Comment: Would this work in node.js ? And how would I put mulitple rectangles together ? Im really sorry if I seem like an idiot I havent worked with canvases before thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry I’m not familiar with node.js :) It should work to build several images in canvas using different coordinates

Comment: Hi Junaid.ioane and welcome to Stack Overflow. There's a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for new users and articles on the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) with more information about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) etc. Canvases can be used to generate geometric images, as can SVG or even HTML and CSS for simple examples. While possibly more easily performed in a browser, Googling "canvas support in node" suggests there are packages that may be suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a perfect example for a simple canvas script

```js
// find canvas in DOM
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// const declaration
const count = 5
const size = 100

// set canvas size
canvas.width = count * size
canvas.height = size

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  // random colour
  ctx.fillStyle = '#' + (Math.random() * 16777216 | 0).toString(16)
  // draw rectangle
  ctx.fillRect(i * size, 0, size, size)
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

In node.js you would need a library that would add canvas support because it's only available in the browser by default.